# Как логировать данные subprocess в тг бот

Tags: python, aiogram, jar, subprocess

я запускаю jar файл так:

```py
import subprocess

subprocess.call([java8_path, '-jar', core_path])
```

и все работает и выводится в консоль логи jar файла, но я не могу реализовать одну вещь:

мне нужно чтобы логи из jar файла не выводились прямо в консоль, а чтобы их отправлял мне тг бот

```py
from aiogram import types

async def send_logs(jar_log_text: str):
    await bot.send_message(0000000, jar_log_text)
```

но я не знаю потоки и подпоцессы и не понимаю как это сделать, помогите пожалуйста

Comment: Какой вопрос в итоге: который в заголовке или который в тексте?

Comment: @Эникейщик ой просто мне нужно было 2 вещи, а первую я решил, нужен ответ к вопросу уоторый в тексте

Comment: значит исправьте заголовок

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы просто получить вывод подпроцесса, можно использовать [`subprocess.check_output`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output), пример:

```
import subprocess

jar_log_text = subprocess.check_output([java8_path, '-jar', core_path])
```

Но для асинхронной работы (т.к. у вас `aiogram`) лучше использовать функции из модуля `asyncio` (см. https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-subprocess.html):

```
import asyncio


async def run_something():
    # Ждем запуска процесса
    proc = await asyncio.create_subprocess_exec(
        *[java8_path, '-jar', core_path],
        stdout=asyncio.subprocess.PIPE,
        stderr=asyncio.subprocess.PIPE,
    )

    # Ждем завершения процесса и получаем все что он вывел
    stdout, stderr = await proc.communicate()
    # в stdout - обычный вывод субпроцесса
    # в stderr - вывод ошибок

    if stdout:
        await bot.send_message(0000000, f'[stdout]\n{stdout.decode("utf-8")}')
    if stderr:
        await bot.send_message(0000000, f'[stderr]\n{stderr.decode("utf-8")}')
```

Если бот запущен на Windows, то вместо `.decode("utf-8")` нужно использовать `.decode("cp866")`.

Comment: когда неправильно указал путь до jar файла, то тг бот отправил что неправильная директория, но когда исправил не отправляет ничего, и если в консоль написать команду jar файла, то выходит это:

await bot.send_message(self.user, f'[stdout]\n{stdout.decode("utf-8")}')
                                                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xa7 in position 18610: invalid start byte

Comment: А где запускаете бота? Если на windows, то замените utf-8 на cp866

Comment: @CreeperHack, если честно, ничего не понял, что вы хотели сказать

Comment: Если возник новый вопрос, задайте его отдельно, а не меняйте исходный вопрос. Если мой ответ помог, вы можете отметить его принятым и/или проголосовать "за".

Comment: Если вы применили мой ответ (субпроцесс запускается, данные из него прходят), но у вас возникли какие-то сложности - это уже новый вопрос, его нужно задать отдельно.

Comment: @CreeperHack по поводу вашей правки вопроса - нужно смотреть как jar принимает данные, через стандартный ввод (грубо говоря, после запуска пользователь что-то вводит с клавиатуры) или через параметры командной строки. В первом случае нужно в `.communicate()` через параметр данные передать. Во втором - через параметры командной строки (в списке  `*[java8_path, '-jar', core_path]` после core_path добавить)

Comment: В принципе, в новом вопросе желательно описать, как с этими jar файлами вы бы работали без бота

Comment: спасибо вам, я уже нашел ответы

Comment: этот код выводит логи после завершения работы с jar файлом, а мне нужно чтобы я запустил jar файл, и все логи мне приходили в тг и чтобы можно было выполнять команды jar файла с тг бота

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1518084/как-сделать-чтобы-все-логи-jar-файла-отправлял-тг-бот-и-чтобы-можно-было-выполн
вот я задал новый вопрос, надеюсь поможите