# как выводить subprocess.stdout в телеграм бот в python

Tags: python, aiogram, jar, subprocess

мне надо сделать так, чтобы `stdout` подпроцесса отправлялся мне в телеграм через бот

вот мой код, в котором я ввожу команды подпроцессу через телеграм бот

```
proc = subprocess.Popen(
    [java8_path, '-jar', 'spigot-1.12.2.jar'],
    stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
    cwd=server_path,
)

@dp.message_handler()
async def input_msg(msg: types.Message):
    proc.stdin.write(msg.text.encode())
```

Comment: вот ответ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76165006/how-to-log-subprocess-data-to-tg-bot/76221645#76221645

Answer (score 0):

Вероятно, вам нужно что-то вроде этого:

```py
import asyncio
import logging
import subprocess
from threading import Thread

from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, executor, types

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)

bot = Bot(token='ТВОЙ ТОКЕН')

dp = Dispatcher(bot)

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

proc = None

text_to_send = ''

chat_id = -1


def read_stdout():
    global text_to_send
    while True:
        output = proc.stdout.readline()
        if output != '':
            text_to_send += output.decode()


async def sender():
    global text_to_send
    while True:
        await asyncio.sleep(3)
        if text_to_send != '':
            await bot.send_message(chat_id, text_to_send)
            text_to_send = ''


@dp.message_handler(commands=['start'])
async def start(msg: types.Message):
    global chat_id, proc
    if not proc:
        proc = subprocess.Popen(
            [java8_path, '-jar', 'spigot-1.12.2.jar'],
            stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
            stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
            cwd=server_path,
        )
        chat_id = msg.chat.id
        th = Thread(target=read_stdout)
        th.start()


@dp.message_handler()
async def input_msg(msg: types.Message):
    global chat_id
    if proc:
        proc.stdin.write((msg.text + '\n').encode())
        proc.stdin.flush()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    loop.create_task(sender())
    executor.start_polling(dp)
```

Comment: а есть что-то лучше чем бесконечный цикл? например указать в Popen функцию для stdout которая отправляет его в тг